# std::vector's push_back() causing a strange compile-time error message

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, push-back

My snippet of code:

```
void
RMWavefrontFileImporter::loadVertexIntoVector(
    const std::vector<std:string> lineElements,
    std::vector<const RM3DVertex>* vertices)
{
    assert(vertices);

    std::unique_ptr<const RM3DVertex> verticeRef = verticeWithElements(lineElements);

    const RM3DVertex* vertex = vertexRef.get();
    assert(vertex);

    vertices->push_back(*vertex);
}
```

The error message I'm getting:

**Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'const RM3DVertice *'**

I'm failing to see the problem.  Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `vertices->push_back(vertice);` ? Also, you probably need to release that unique_ptr...

Comment: @Pubby No, vertices is declared as `std::vector<const RM3DVertice>` and I'd say no to the second part too. The unique_ptr seems to be holding a heap allocated object solely for the purpose of pushing back a copy into the vector. Releasing would leak memory.

Comment: Error line is: `vertices->push_back(*vertice);`? Compiler is complaining about this line?

Comment: You're sure about this: `std::vector<const RM3DVertice>*`? A vector (who's objects must support CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible (until C++11) of `const Type` seems like its problematic. Or i need to get out more. one of the two. Shouldn't that be ``std::vector<RM3DVertice>`?

Comment: @antonte - It seems to be caused by that line, but it's not IN that line of code.  The error points me to some code in a file called "memory" that is called as a direct result of that line I wrote.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I take it in the end you meant "std::vector<RM3DVertice>*"? (just missing the final * in case you wanna fix that)

Comment: I find it fascinating that the irregular plural of *vertex* being *vertices* has created a new singular form *vertice*, which is the opposite of what ordinarily happens—you would expect to see *vertexes*.

Comment: @Jon - Will change that... my main tongue is Spanish which is the cause of my mistake.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @diegoreymendez: No problem. I have heard native English speakers say *vertice* sometimes, but had never seen it in code.

Comment: @diegoreymendez to answer your comment-question from what seems like awhile ago now (sry), yes, though in such circumstancs I'm a references fan myself, if not just outright returning a vector and relying on RVO. You code, though. You got the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value type `T` of a `std::vector<T>` needs to be CopyInsertible or MoveInsertible. To be either, it is necessary to call the moral equivalent of

```
T* tptr = <allocate-memory-over-here-and-make-it-look-like-a-T*>
new(tptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args);
```

With `T` being a `const` type this doesn't work, e.g., because there is no conversion from `T*` to `void*` if `T` is of the form `X const`. You want to remove the `const` from `std::vector<const RM3DVertice>`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  So just to make sure I understood: by making the vector members const I was getting into the way of the std::vector code (which needs them not to be const and be instead CopyInsertible + MoveInsertible)?

Comment: @diegoreymendez: Yes, that is correct. In C++11 you can get away with very little operations on your type `T` but there are some minimal requirements which cannot be avoided.